# Setting mobX state from inside a React-Apollo component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, mobx, react-apollo

When trying to set the onChange state of an input element, I am unable to change the state. React-Apollo components need a child function that returns some JSX. Inside the child function It appears that the `this`object is being inherited, but I cant get it to actually change.

If I remove the `<Mutation/>` component all together then everything works as expected. Is there something special about React-Apollo components or the way the `this` object interacts with arrow functions?

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { extendObservable } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const mutation = gql`here is a mutation`

class Why extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    extendObservable(this, {
      text: '',
    })
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.text = e.target.value;
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={mutation}>
      { () => (
          <div>
            {console.log(this)}
            <input  name="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Text"
                    type="text"
                    value={this.text}
                    onChange={this.onChange}/>
          </div>
        )
      }
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
}

export default observer(Why);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the state is actually changing but the component render didn't react for you.
It happens because `observer` components only tracks data that directly accessed by the render function, in your case you have a function that don't.

a simple solution is to use the `<Observer />` component from `mobx-react`:

```
  render () {
      return (
          <Mutation mutation={mutation}>
          { () => (
              <Observer>
              {() => (
                   <div>
                   {console.log(this)}
                    <input  name="text"
                        placeholder="Enter Text"
                        type="text"
                        value={this.text}
                        onChange={this.onChange}/>
                   </div>
              )}
            </Observer>
           )
         }
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
```